# ValueError: invalid __array_struct__

Tags: python-3.x

I tried running code about map data processing while calling the geopandas library function gp. An error occurred in GeoDataFrame(X_df, geometry=ss), how to solve it`
problem as follow：

```
`File "D:\\generate_training_test.py", line 10, in \<module\>file_generator = fileGen(FEATURE_PATH, OUTPUT_PATH)
File "D:\\utils\\fileGen.py", line 15, in
__init__
self.create_dataset()
File "D:\\utils\\fileGen.py", line 28, in
create_dataset
self.\__construct_training_test()
File "D:\\utils\\fileGen.py", line 39, in
\__construct_training_test
self.X_df_train, self.Y_df_train, self.X_df_test, self.Y_df_test = get_training_test_data(self.X_df, self.Y_df, draw=self.draw)
File "D:\\zhang\\biyesheji\\git\\utils\\drive_test_route_journal.py", line 141, in get_training_test_data
X_df_test, Y_df_test = get_samples_test_route(X_df, Y_df, route)
File "D:\\utils\\drive_test_route_journal.py", line 112, in get_samples_test_route
geo_df = gp.GeoDataFrame(X_df, geometry=ss)
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\geopandas\\geodataframe.py", line 188, in __init__
self.set_geometry(geometry, inplace=True, crs=crs)
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\geopandas\\geodataframe.py", line 347, in set_geometry
frame\[geo_column_name\] = level
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\geopandas\\geodataframe.py", line 1439, in __setitem__
crs = getattr(self, "crs", None)
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\geopandas\\geodataframe.py", line 431, in crs
return self.geometry.crs
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\geopandas\\geodataframe.py", line 217, in \_get_geometry
geo_cols = list(self.columns\[self.dtypes == "geometry"\])
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\indexes\\base.py", line 5337, in __getitem__
key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)`your text`
File "C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid __array_struct__
```